# How to add libphonenumber asyoutype to input

Tags: javascript, svelte, libphonenumber

I'm trying to add asYouType from [libphonenumber-js](https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js) to my svelte project.

I have a custom input component that uses 2 way binding to get the value, I have read the documentation and found to use it via `const asYouType = new AsYouType('US')` but I can't find any examples of how to add this to an input.

How can I add this to my input to format the data?

```
    <Input
        label="firstName"
        bind:value={userData.firstName}
    />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add onChange handler to input in svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278480/add-onchange-handler-to-input-in-svelte)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with a `firstName` input and a phone number?